# How can I Identify noise from newly built PC when the only moving parts are the fans?

Tags: troubleshooting, desktop-computer

I just recently built a new PC, however it has been producing a noise that sounds like a chirp / scratch / grind. The only moving parts in this PC are the fans, and I've checked to make sure no wires are getting caught.

It initially happened when I was performing R/W operations on my older SATA SSDs, but I heard it a few times after restarting and getting to the Windows login screen, as well as when writing to the newer NVME drives.

I've ran Cinebench as well as FurMark and did not hear the noise during either benchmark.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could make this type of sound? Could this be the motherboard making the noise? Is it something to worry about?

Comment: Sounds like a HDD to me.

Comment: @sawdust I have no HDDs in this build - two SATA SSDs, two M.2 NVMEs.

Comment: "I'm hoping that it's coming from the SATA SSDs" - That would be impossible.  SSDs have no moving parts.  There is nothing about them that could make sound.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that they have no moving parts, however neither does a motherboard, and yet it can make audible sounds. If you look, I even mention that the only moving parts in my case are the fans, and yet the sound exists. Did you watch the video? Any ideas on what could be making that noise? It only ever happens when performing R/W operations.

Comment: Is the noise that bit that sounds a bit like a chipmunk? Might be a PSU issue. Transformers and capacitors make noise at times.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I managed to record a quick video of the noise, it's linked in the post if you want to take a look!

Comment: @JosephP Yeah, I watched and heard  the video. Sorry if that was not clear. It sounds a bit like a chipmunk. Sounds like a PSU issue.

Comment: "however neither does a motherboard, and yet it can make audible sounds" - What you are hearing is coil whine. **Your SSD isn't making noise.**

Comment: @Ramhound It's not 'coil whine', it's the motherboard VRM rattling when switching power states. You really only sought to correct the most simple error, without even offering an iota of help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to identify the noise by running a stress test from within CPU-Z.

When starting the test (or when the CPU power state switches), the noise originates from the motherboard VRM (Voltage Regulator Modules) section.